# How to handle client disconnected error on global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am developing a web application on ASP.NET with c#, when a trace error occurs on the website I store the error in a database from the global.asax using the `Application_Error` method. This is working fine but there are many errors occurring like client disconnected. How can I handle this error from global.asax it will not be stored in the database?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Can you provide some examples?  Maybe show the code you're using to handle application errors and tell us what specific errors/exceptions it's either handling and shouldn't or not handling and should?  If you can include information you gathered by stepping through the code when it's not doing what you want it to do that would be helpful as well.

Comment: When you see "Client Disconnected" as part of the message in the Exception, just ignore it and don't store it in the database.

Comment: ok thanks i solved it by ignore it...Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to track them at all, I would suggest creating a black list of ignorable exceptions and compare against them using the type and partial message text as the comparison.  The black list could be stored in a DB table that you just read on `ApplicationStart` and cached or you could just hard code them.

You could also extend the solution by storing a count of how often these blacklisted exceptions are getting caught and store them in the application cache.  Then have an admin page that could list the count or average frequency etc. in case you need to diagnose if these exceptions are actually occurring due to something valid that should be looked into.

It all comes down to how important these exceptions are to you and if they do become important in the future, how easily you can diagnose the issue with what tools you have at hand.